# Loop through array to check for the correct name using Get-NetAdapter

Tags: powershell

Recently I put a script together that will collect some data from a computer.
While extracting this data some of it is being sorted by name.

`$BTMacAdress = $(Get-NetAdapter -Name "Bluetooth Network Connection").MacAddress`

When you use this script on a Spanish machine the name will change to "Conexión de red Bluetooth".

I have created an array with all the connection names in different languages. How can I make it so it will loop through the array and check if the correct name is in this array?

I tried to put the array in place of "Bluetooth Network Connection" but that had little succes.

Comment: Something like `Get-NetAdapter -Name *Bluetooth*` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Alternatively, this should work `Get-NetAdapter |? {$_.Name -like "*Bluetooth*"}`.  Tying with the answer below you could then wrap the same way with `(Get-NetAdapter |? {$_.Name -like "*Bluetooth*"}).MacAddress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter by media type

```
Get-NetAdapter | where PhysicalMediaType -eq "Bluetooth"
```

This of course also works the way you're using it:

```
$BTMacAdress = (Get-NetAdapter | where PhysicalMediaType -eq "Bluetooth").MacAddress
```

Comment: This was the solution I ended up using. Thank you for your input.